# pairing two set of data in Python, any idea?

Tags: python

I am trying to pair two sets of data based on their difference and minimize the standard deviation

```
set1= (300, 420, 541, 600)
set2= (1470, 1250, 1250, 1360)
```

so, three examples here
#1

```
(300, 420, 541, 600)
(1250, 1250, 1360, 1470)
```

difference is `(950, 830, 819, 870)` so the stdv is `59.35`

#2

```
(300, 420, 541, 600)
(1470, 1250, 1360, 1250)
```

difference is `(1170, 830, 819, 650)` so the stdv is `217.99`

#3

```
(300, 420, 541, 600)
(1250, 1470, 1360, 1250)
```

difference is `(950, 1050, 819, 650)` so the stdv is `127.98`

so #1 is desired with smaller stdv

How this can be achieved in Python? Thanks in advance.

so #1 is desired with smaller stdv

```
(300, 420, 541, 600)
(1250, 1250, 1360, 1470)
```

I couldn't think of how, it was previously done in access

Update:

the data came in as dataframe as

```
data1 = {'col1': ["A", "B", "C", "C"], 'col2': [300, 420, 541, 600]}
date2= {'col1': ["A", "C", "B", "D"], 'col2': [1470, 1250, 1250, 1360]}
```

using data1.col2 and data2.col2 like set1 and set2

I wanna see

```
data1  = {'col1': ["A", "B", "C", "C"], 'col2': [300, 420, 541, 600], 'col3': [1250, 1250, 1360, 1470]}
```

with the new 'col3' filled with the order from min_diff_s2

Update2: Can I safely say if I want final data1 with set2's col1 information, does a join based on the min_diff_s2 is good?

Comment: *Sets* are unordered. Do you perhaps have *lists*?

Comment: How did you previously do it in Access? Presumably similar logic will also apply in python, albeit with different syntax

Comment: yes, it comes with dataframe table, I am reconstructing it in Python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are *tuples*, not *sets*.

```
set1 = (300, 420, 541, 600)
set2 = (1470, 1250, 1250, 1360)
```

First, let's define a function that, given any two tuples, will return the standard deviation of the difference between them:

```
from statistics import stdev

def diff_std(s1, s2):
    return stdev(i1 - i2 for i1, i2 in zip(s1, s2))
```

You want *all possible permutations* of one of the tuple. If you compare the other tuple to all possible permutations of the first tuple, you will have compared all possible combinations of the two tuples.

Then, apply the subtraction and standard deviation to obtain a single value, and find the combination that gives you the smallest standard deviation.

```
from itertools import permutations

set1_perms = permutations(set1)

min_diff_s1, min_diff_s2 = min(((s1, set2) for s1 in set1_perms), 
                    key=lambda x: diff_std(x[0], x[1]))
```

Which gives the combination you specified in #1:

```
min_diff_s1 = (600, 300, 420, 541)
min_diff_s2 = (1470, 1250, 1250, 1360)
```

---

With your dataframes, you need to do the same thing (almost):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ["A", "B", "C", "C"], 'col2': [300, 420, 541, 600]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ["A", "C", "B", "D"], 'col2': [1470, 1250, 1250, 1360]})
```

A couple of differences:

- you want to put the data from `df2` into `df1`, so let's permute `df2.col2` instead of permuting the first set like we did above
- Pandas columns are `Series` objects which inherently support element-wise subtraction and standard deviation, so we can define the `diff_std` function to account for this:
- We don't really need to get the first set's values again, since we never permute them.

```
def diff_std(s1, s2):
    return (s1 - s2).std()

set2_perms = permutations(df2.col2.values)
min_diff_s2 = min(set_perms, 
                  key=lambda x: diff_std(df1.col2, x))
```

In `diff_std`, `s2` is a tuple and `s1` is a `pd.Series` object. Subtracting a tuple from a `Series` does element-wise subtraction and returns a `Series`. Then we take the `std()` of that resulting `Series` object.

We don't really care about the first set, since we didn't permute it.

Now that we have `min_diff_s2`, we can set the column of `df1`:

```
df1["col3"] = min_diff_s2
```

Which results in:

```
  col1  col2  col3
0    A   300  1250
1    B   420  1250
2    C   541  1360
3    C   600  1470
```

Comment: how does it work if the set1 and set2 are tables, and each field of the tables are used, thank you

Comment: @Connie I don't understand what you mean by that. Please either update your question or ask a new question with example data that correctly represents your actual data

Comment: if I bring tables in as dataframes, data1 = {'col1': ["A", "B", "C", "C"], 'col2': [300, 420, 541, 600]} and date2= {'col1': ["A", "C", "B", "D"], 'col2': [1470, 1250, 1250, 1360]}, using data1.col2 and data2.col2, and wanna see data1 data1 = {'col1': ["A", "B", "C", "C"], 'col2': [300, 420, 541, 600], 'col3': [1250, 1250, 1360, 1470]}, sorry, I am very new on this

Comment: @ConnieXu as you can see, comments aren't a good place to share data. Don't edit _my answer_ with your data, [edit _your question!_](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74720981/edit)

Comment: I am sorry, let me edit on the question

Comment: @ConnieXu see my edited answer. [A reminder since you're new here](/help/someone-answers): be sure to upvote any answers that helped you, and accept the answer that best answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have tuples not sets as that is how they are written. As for getting their difference you can use a comprehension:

```
>>> set1= (300, 420, 541, 600)
>>> set2= (1470, 1250, 1250, 1360)
>>> diff = tuple(s1 - s2 for s1, s2 in zip(set1, set2))
>>> diff
(-1170, -830, -709, -760)
```

And for the standard deviation there is a function for this in the [`statistics`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.stdev) library:

```
>>> from statistics import stdev
>>> stdev(diff)
207.83867942870177
```